# World War I Branch of Service

Tags: world-war-1

I am researching an individual that served in WW I.  His branch of service indicated "M".  Was the "M" referring to the Marines, the Medical Corps, or something else?

He was a dentist later in life.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  Which country are we looking at here?  The UK? The US? Canada? Germany? France?  Also, what record are you looking at?  Abbreviations can mean different things on different records.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  I agree with the previous comment. Please tell us what record you are looking at -- when you strip all context from a question, it is difficult to write an answer.  There are many instances where the instructions for filling out the forms are also available to researchers, but we can't tell you where to find them if we don't know what you have.